# Rendering components in React Router not working

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom

I am working on an inventory management system for a small business that needs to be fast, so I am using React. I'm not the most versed in react router so I am following a tutorial and using what I already have ready to go instead of the simple `h4` heading the tutorial uses. However, I'm stumped at the very first part: Setting up routes.  As of right now, I am just trying to set the routes up so if I type localhost3000/ims, it renders the InvSys component. However it's not working.

This is my index.js:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDom from 'react-dom';
import './index.css'
import Nav from './Navbar'
import InvSys from './ItemSystem'
import {BrowserRouter as Router, Switch, Route} from 'react-router-dom';

function ItemList(){ //stateless functional component; needs to return JSX
  return (
  <Router>
    <div className="container">
      <Nav />
      <Route exact path="/" component={Home}/>
      <Route exact path="/ims" component={InvSys}/>
    </div>
  </Router>
  )
}

const Home = () => (
  <div className = 'container'>
    <h1>Mel-Tex I.M.S</h1>
  </div>
)

ReactDom.render(<ItemList />, document.getElementById('root') );
```

This is my InvSys:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import './index.css';
// JS
// const input = document.getElementById('myText');
// const inputValue = input.value
// React
// value, onChange

const ItemSystem = () => {

  const[itemType,setItemType] = useState('')
  const[itemDesc,setItemDesc] = useState('')
  const[itemWeight,setItemWeight] = useState('')
  const[family,setFamily] = useState('')
  const[itemPrice,setItemPrice] = useState('')
  
  const[inventory,setInventory] = useState([])

  const handleSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    if(itemDesc && itemType && itemWeight){
      const item ={id: new Date().getTime().toString(),itemType,itemDesc,itemWeight,family,itemPrice}
      setInventory((inventory)=>{
        return [...inventory,item]
      });
      setItemType('');
      setItemDesc('');
      setItemWeight('');
      setFamily('');
      setItemPrice('');
    }
  }

  return <>
  <article>

    <form className='form' onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
      <div className='form-control'>
        <label htmlFor='itemType'>Item Code: </label>
        <input
        type='text'
        id='itemType'
        name="itemType"
        value={itemType}
        onChange= {(e) => setItemType(e.target.value)}
        />

      </div>
      <div className='form-control'>
        <label htmlFor='itemDesc'>Item Desc: </label>
        <input
        type='text'
        id='itemDesc'
        name="itemDesc"
        value={itemDesc}
        onChange= {(e) => setItemDesc(e.target.value)}
        />
      </div>
      <div className='form-control'>
        <label htmlFor='itemWeight'>Item Weight: </label>
        <input
        type='text'
        id='itemWeight'
        name="itemWeight"
        value={itemWeight}
        onChange= {(e) => setItemWeight(e.target.value)}
        />
      </div>
      <div className='form-control'>
      <label htmlFor='family'>Item Family: </label>
      <input
      type='text'
      id='family'
      name="family"
      value={family}
      onChange= {(e) => setFamily(e.target.value)}
      />

    </div>
    <div className='form-control'>
      <label htmlFor='itemPrice'>List Price: </label>
      <input
      type='text'
      id='itemPrice'
      name="itemPrice"
      value={itemPrice}
      onChange= {(e) => setItemPrice(e.target.value)}
      />
    </div>
      <button type='submit'>Add Item </button>
    </form>
    <>
      <h3>Items Added</h3>
      {
        inventory.map((item) => {
          const {id, itemType, itemDesc, itemWeight, family, itemPrice} = item
          return <div key={id}>
            <h4>Item Code: {itemType}, Description: {itemDesc}, Weight: {itemWeight}, Family: {family} List Price: {itemPrice}</h4>


          </div>

      })
    }
    </>
  </article>
  </>;
};

export default ItemSystem;
```

Here is a link to codesandbox where I have gotten to the same point and have the same result: https://codesandbox.io/s/rendering-components-in-react-router-not-working-forked-xtyfs?file=/src/App.js

Comment: Can you describe what the issue is, what exactly isn't working? I'm going to guess you are working on trying to either implement navigation in your `Nav` component or between `Home` and InvSys`?

Comment: As of right now, I am just trying to set the routes up so if i type localhost3000/ims, it renders the InvSys

Comment: Is that not working? What is the actual result you are seeing?

Comment: What shows up is just the nav and a blank white screen. When i comment out the navbar, its just a blank screen. I don't have any errors like I would if react-router was outdated or if I didn't have routes imported correctly either.

Comment: Copy pasted your code into a *running* [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/rendering-components-in-react-router-not-working-vlg9t) it it's working there. I didn't have your `Nav` component though so that is commented out. Try forking this sandbox and editing it to reproduce the issue you have and link it in your question.

Comment: You can see how manually going to the url for the routes doesn't work on your code too and I am not sure why those won't render

Comment: I don't follow, I tested both routes and they both render. "/" renders the home page with the header, and "/ims" renders a form with input fields. Are you sure you're entering correct paths?

Comment: Yes, does the way I am rendering the app have something to do with it? That is all I changed between our code.  https://codesandbox.io/s/rendering-components-in-react-router-not-working-forked-xtyfs?file=/src/App.js

Comment: Perhaps, though it's not immediately clear why. Here's my earlier sandbox but with a simple Nav: https://codesandbox.io/s/rendering-components-in-react-router-not-working-forked-dvi5v?file=/src/index.js Why are you trying to define your react component ***and*** render it into the DOM in the same file? It *should* still work, but it's more common to do so in a base `index.js` file.

Comment: I usually change at the end. While I develop, its easier for me to have everything on one page because I can quickly see what I am doing and usually its faster for me to find a problem. I just tried it in a base index.js file and it still didn't work with npm start or in the codesandbox

Comment: Well, navigation is working for me in both the sandboxes I've shared with you. Perhaps there is something else going on elsewhere in your code, or it's just the weird `ReactDOM.render` in the same file causing an issue.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I suppose I will start over and do the routes first, since that seems to be the most direct way to get them to work. As you said, there may be something broken somewhere else and at the very least if I have all of the pieces I will be moving forward.

Comment: I edited that second sandbox to direct render to the DOM in the same file and it still works for me.

Comment: I saw that and literally just tried copy and pasting and it didn’t work. I believe it was something wrong with the dependencies because even reinstalling didn’t work. However, after starting over it all started working again